# How do I store pointers/symbols to external shared library functions in a struct?

Tags: rust, shared-libraries, symbols, borrow-checker

Basically, I want to load a shared library (with the libloading crate), get a few function pointers, and store them in a struct. Later, I want to access these functions without having to look them up again.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

type MyFunctionType = fn() -> i32;

pub struct MyStruct {
    library: Library,
    func1: Symbol<'static, MyFunctionType>,
    func2: Symbol<'static, MyFunctionType>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new(library_path: &str) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let library = unsafe {
            Library::new(library_path)?
        };

        // Use the `get` method to obtain function pointers by symbol name.
        let func1: Symbol<MyFunctionType> = unsafe { library.get(b"func1")? };
        let func2: Symbol<MyFunctionType> = unsafe { library.get(b"func2")? };

        Ok(MyStruct {
            library,
            func1,
            func2,
        })
    }

    pub fn call_func1(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.func1)()
    }

    pub fn call_func2(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.func2)()
    }
}
```

The initial error is:

```
  --> src/main.rs:30:54
   |
25 |         let library = unsafe {
   |             ------- binding `library` declared here
...
30 |         let func1: Symbol<MyFunctionType> = unsafe { library.get(b"func1")? };
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                                      |
   |                                                      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                      argument requires that `library` is borrowed for `'static`
...
38 |     }
   |     - `library` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I've tried various changes, such as adding lifetimes, reference counters and even a Cow, but every 'fix' seems to introduce another compiler issue.

Any rust experts know how I can fix this? It feels like I'm doing things the proper way but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Here's the signature for `Library::get`:

```
pub unsafe fn get<'lib, T>(
    &'lib self,
    symbol: &[u8]
) -> Result<Symbol<'lib, T>, Error>
```

`get` returns a `Symbol` with the lifetime `'lib`, which is the lifetime of the `Library` instance you invoked the `get` method on. In plain English, this function is saying:

> I'm returning a `Symbol` that contains references to a `Library`. Don't let anyone drop (or move) `Library` while the `Symbol` is alive, lest the pointers [dangle](https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/dangling-pointer-in-c/)!

But in `MyStruct::new`, you attempt to move library while a symbol derived from it exists (edited for clarity):

```
let library = ... // library created as a local variable
let func1 = library.get(b"func1");
Ok(MyStruct {
   library, // library moved while func1 is alive
   func1,
})
```

The natural followup is "well how do I avoid moving `library`, while keeping it in the same struct as `func1`"? There are ways, but in idiomatic rust, we avoid "self referencing structs" where possible. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) has a good writeup on why, but TLDR most structs in Rust can be moved, which would invalidate their self-references.

### Solution

Don't keep `library` and the `func`s in the same struct, like this:

```
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

type MyFunctionType = fn() -> i32;
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    func1: Symbol<'a, MyFunctionType>,
    func2: Symbol<'a, MyFunctionType>,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new(library: &'a Library) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let func1: Symbol<MyFunctionType> = unsafe { library.get(b"func1")? };
        let func2: Symbol<MyFunctionType> = unsafe { library.get(b"func2")? };
        Ok(Self {
            func1,
            func2,
        })
    }

    pub fn call_func1(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.func1)()
    }

    pub fn call_func2(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.func2)()
    }
}

pub fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let library = unsafe {
        Library::new("/path/to/your/lib.so")?
    };
    let funcs = MyStruct::new(&library);

    Ok(())

}
```